# add page name in the url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just started .htaccess so I do not know too much about it, I try to google it but failed so I post my question here, I am sorry if the question is silly for you. My question is.
I use this code in .htaccess page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /learn/php/htaccess/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?n=$1&p=$2
```

when I enter this url:

```
http://localhost/learn/php/htaccess/page/number
```

it works fine. but I also want to add index.php (page name) in the url. I tried this:

```
http://localhost/learn/php/htaccess/index.php/page/number
```

AND

```
http://localhost/learn/php/htaccess/index.php?page/number
```

but failed. How can I do this?
I simply want to do that if I add another page then I am not sure but I have to use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /learn/php/htaccess/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?n=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ another.php?x=$1&y=$2
```

but how can I open the another.php page with this format?
thanks

Comment: You will need to defined another rule (or alter your regex) to count for the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a few conditions to your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /learn/php/htaccess/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?n=$1&p=$2
```

As for routing to another page, you'll need to distinguish the difference between the two routes. For example, given a url:

```
http://localhost/learn/php/htaccess/foo/bar
```

where should it get routed to?

```
index.php?n=foo&p=bar
```

or

```
another.php?x=foo&y=bar
```

?

htaccess knows nothing about the content, only the URL and a regex pattern to match it, so unless you differentiate between the two, you can't route the same thing to two different scripts.

Comment: @Mubashar if you want index.php to handle PATH INFO, then it's not up to htaccess to handle that, you have to script your index.php to check the `PATH_INFO` server variable and parse out the `page/number` and correctly return the script

Answer (score 1):

You can just make it easy like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA]
```

in your index.php you put this code

```
   $data = explode("/",$_GET['data']);
   $page = $data[0];
   $number = $data[1];
```